# saving MySQL settings

Tags: mysql, wamp

how can i save permanently settings of MySQL ?
i got MySQL from WAMP, and there is no my.cnf file, there is a my.ini file !
how can i set some global variable,

Comment: `my.ini`, `my.cnf`, `my.blabla` - does it matter what the file's extension is?

Comment: If you don't know that my.cnf = my.ini then yes it absolutely matters what the file's extension is...  For example in my apigen folder I have three files called apigen.bat, apigen.phar and apigen.php - so if I want to edit the settings for this program I can just choose any file to edit, because the extension doesn't matter???  Clearly not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Drive:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\my.ini`

this is the place to save settings.

Answer (score 5):

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com) uses the my.ini file.

To get to your my.ini file, just click the WAMP tray icon and hover over the 'MySQL' menu, and click 'my.ini'.

1. Edit your my.ini file and under the **[mysqld]** section, add this:

   `setting-name=setting-value`   , example: event-scheduler=on
2. restart all services

You do not need to use quotes around either the setting or value.

Answer (score 2):

Global [system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-system-variables.html) must be [specified](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/program-options.html) using the command line or SQL commands (runtime/session) or by configuration file (permanent).

Comment: how to do that in configuration file ? i opened my.ini there are no such settings :( i'm able to change in MySQL console, but all the settings gets erased after a restart

Comment: Take a look at the documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html

Comment: i tried with `set sql_select_limit=5000;` and `set GLOBAL sql_select_limit=5000;` and also in the my.ini, all approach fails :(

Comment: @Sourav - First, the keyword `set` need only be used on the command line.  In your ini file, just use the format `optname=value` (without set).  Second, any time you change the main server ini file, you have to restart the server for the changes to take effect.  Did you do that?  Verify the settings by running `phpinfo()` and check to see that your options are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same question because in WAMP we only have a `my.ini` file instead of `my.conf`.

Through a SQL statement, proceeded as follow:

```
mysql> SET global max_heap_table_size=524288000;
mysql> SET global tmp_table_size=524288000;
```

but when restarted the server, the query:

```
select @@global.tmp_table_size, @@global.max_heap_table_size
```

returned the old values by default.

Then edited `my.ini` file ading the following statements:

```
max_heap_table_size=524288000
tmp_table_size=524288000
```

and the changes were permanent.