# Viewing earlier Query log - MySQL

Tags: mysql, wamp

I want to see mysql queries [history, log] [select,insert,update,...] [which i executed] !
Can anyone help me on this ?

I'm using MySQL Version :    5.5.8  [which i got from WAMP]
I tried changing settings from console, and failed ! [change gets lost after restart]
i've asked it before, but no working answer !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755696/saving-mysql-settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following settings in `my.ini`:

```
[mysqld]  
port=3306    
long_query_time = 1  
slow_query_log = 1  
slow_query_log_file = "E:/wamp/logs/slowquery.log"  
log = "E:/wamp/logs/genquery.log"
```

Answer (score 7):

[Sourav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813402/) no longer works. As of July 2013, you need:

```
general-log=1
general-log-file = "C:\wamp\logs\mysql_general.log"
```