# PHPUnit/ Silverstripe Testing returns "Couldn't run query", "Table doesn't exist"

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit, wamp, silverstripe

I have two Silverstripe websites running in the same WAMP 2.5 environment, sharing the same _ss_environment.php file (which sets database permissions etc.)

Both are:

- Silverstripe 3.2.0RC1
- Installed/ updated via Composer
- PHPUnit 3.7.28

When I go to localhost.example/dev/tests I get completely different behaviour:

Site #1 runs the tests without any issues and returns the expected output.

Site #2 won't run any test and comes back with this sort of error:

> Couldn't run query:
>
> SELECT DISTINCT "Group"."ClassName", "Group"."LastEdited",
>   "Group"."Created", "Group"."Title", "Group"."Description",
>   "Group"."Code", "Group"."Locked", "Group"."Sort",
>   "Group"."HtmlEditorConfig", "Group"."ParentID", "Group"."ID",             CASE
>   WHEN "Group"."ClassName" IS NOT NULL THEN "Group"."ClassName"             ELSE
>   'Group' END AS "RecordClassName"
>
> FROM "Group"
>
> WHERE ("Group"."ID" = ?)
>
> LIMIT 1
>
> Table 'ss_tmpdb6760406.group' doesn't exist

What the heck is going on?

The Site #2 does have more modules installed but I can't see how that'd affect MySQL permissions/behavior.

The only difference that makes sense to me is Site #1 was a clean composer install on 3.2.0RC1 when Site #2 has been upgraded from an earlier version of Silverstripe (via composer).

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on and how I can get Site #2 to test properly?

Comment: Does the `ss_tmpdb6760406` database have a `Group` table on your localhost?

Comment: did you run dev/build and ?flush on site #2... though group table should be there for ages...

Comment: @3dgoo - I haven't see any ss_tmp databases appear. But I'm unsure of their expected behaviour. Are they created and deleted during unit testing?

Comment: @wmk - built and flushed a number of times for both sites.

Comment: do both sites just share the same database or just the same server? Have you tried setting up sqlite3 for unit tests? See http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/how-to-speed-up-unit-tests-using-sqlite/ (disclaimer: my blog)

Comment: @wmk - both sites share the same database server/ MySQL user/ permissions. If I get totally stuck I'll look into the sqlite3 option.

Comment: as it's just for testing funcitonality and they install a complete new, temporarly database for each test you can totally speed up things by using sqlite, and even more by using sqlite in memory only.
Educated guess: you have some relicts of broken tests in your database? Or user cannot create a new database for the test?

Comment: @BaronGrivet did you ever get this working? I'm having the exact same problem and it's very puzzling.

Comment: @JanneKlouman - for some reason I deleted my answer. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32878259/348485

Comment: @BaronGrivet Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing two unmaintained modules from Site #2 the unit testing is working fine.

I'm guessing there were bugs in the modules but I don't understand how they would have caused database errors in unrelated tests.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My solution was to **completely** purge the contents of `silverstripe-cache` directory (or whichever directory your particular `TEMP_FOLDER` constant points to) and run `sake dev/build`.

Not exactly sure why, but I believe there was an error at some point in building a class manifest and that was cached and was somehow preventing the proper rebuilding of the database schema, resulting in most tables being created except for just a few which were then being inserted into by a fixture file (which then triggered this error). Explains why it worked in the CI server, but not on my local machine. Unit tests are *supposed* to be totally isolated...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you try changing the case-sensitivity setting in MySQL. I've seen similar things before, seemingly randomly occurring, and usually on the main database rather than under test.

I don't have a ton of experience with WAMP, but it sounds like you need to find my.ini ([saving MySQL settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755696/saving-mysql-settings)) and adjust the following setting:

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

Have a look at the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html
And this other question: [How to force case sensitive table names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248735/how-to-force-case-sensitive-table-names)

I can't guarantee that will solve your problem but it's the first place I would check, assuming SQLite is not an option for you as indicated in the comments above.